# Construct new environment with \bgroup...\egroup

Tags: environments, grouping

The following code is just for experiment It would result in a framed box(seem like `\fbox{\parbox{2in}{...}}`). But it fails. What's wrong with my code?

Yet framed box in this example is not my root motive. I want to learn how to construct a new `environment` when syntax of macro(s) has to be splitted and how to use `\bgroup` and `egroup`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myframebox}[1]
{\fbox\bgroup\parbox{#1}\bgroup}
{\egroup\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{myframebox}{2in}
  some thing\par some thing
\end{myframebox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\fbox` needs an ***explicit*** `{` after it and not `\bgroup`. Similarly for `\parbox`.

You can do it, but you need to build the box before `\fbox`ing it. And you need to use the environment form of `\parbox`, that is, `minipage`.

```
\newsavebox{\myframeboxbox}
\newenvironment{myframebox}[1]
 {\begin{lrbox}{\myframeboxbox}\begin{minipage}{#1}}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\myframeboxbox}}}
```

Alternatively

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myframebox}{m +b}
 {\fbox{\parbox{#1}{#2}}}
 {}
```

because `+b` grabs the entire content up to `\end{myframebox}`. The `+` means that blank lines or `\par` tokens are allowed in the contents.

Try the following wrong input to see what is going wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\fbox\bgroup abc\egroup

\parbox{2in}\bgroup some text that should fill two inches and
split across lines\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Yes, `minipage` may be better. `\parbox` in my code is only for an example. I have long been puzzled how to solve the problem that macros used in constructing a new enviroment have to be syntax splitted, as my code showes. Is there any general way to deal with my confusion?

Comment: @lyl Macro arguments are either a single token or tokens enclosed in ***explicit*** `{...}`. Some TeX *primitives* accept arguments enclosed in `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, but this is not general.

Comment: And how to put a `lstlisting` environment in `\fbox` or `\colorbox`?

Comment: @lyl That’s a job for `tcolorbox`

Comment: And where to get the information about `+b`? I don't find it in `xparse` manuel

Comment: @lyl `texdoc usrguide3`